# How to run a reverse prediction with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

I am  quite new to machine learning but  I am looking to solve following problem. It is a kind of  reverse prediction.
I have a lot of inputs and accordingly for each record one output.  So I could do easily a classification and predict the output for an unknown new set of data. 
 The problem I would like to solve is taking one expected outcome and get a classification of the set of input data which will end up on a very high probability to the expected defined output.

To make the problem more complex I would like to have the flexibility to define some of the input criteria which are probably not changeable j(e.g. Male/female)  and add these criteria like filters and get a new Revers prediction - what would be the most relevant important input beside the given one to end up with an expected and defined Outcome.

Let's give an example: I have thousands of records of students including education etc. and the information if they earn normal or extreme money after 10 years of work experience. So if I am a new student I could predict the outcome if I will earn a lot of money or average based on my education, gender, age at degree, what I am studying etc. 
what I would like to get is given the fact that I am male and have an expected age at time of degree, what should I study to have a high probability of earning extreme?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has not an unique or optimal solution, though it can be tackled in several ways, IMO.

The key fact to understand is that you have a loss of information from the vector input to the scalar/categorical output. It is not an 'invertible' or 'reversible' transformation, due to the fact that multiple and very different input vector could lead to the same output value, thus diluting the info component.

Said that, one possible angle of attack for the problem would be to cluster your input vectors, obtaining several relevant clusters for every output value. Then, you could extract those input cluster centers and inspect what are these prototypical values that lead to the desired outcome. This way you will have your desired reverse 'input points of interest'.